# Transitive dependencies for library build flavours on Android using api

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library that is built via Jitpack containing the following build flavors

```
    productFlavors {
    play {
        dimension "default"
        versionName versionString + "-play"
    }

    nonplay {
        dimension "default"
        versionName versionString + "-nonplay"
    }
}
```

In the libraries dependencies section, I include a different dependency based on flavour like so

```
playApi "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesVersion"

nonplayApi "com.mapzen.android:lost:$lostVersion"
```

When I include this library in a new apps build.gradle, with, for example, nonplay

```
implementation ("com.xxx:someproject:1.0.0:nonplay@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
```

I expect to see "com.mapzen.android:lost:$lostVersion" transitively included in my apps dependences list.

However I only see dependencies transitively included that do not use a flavour specific include i.e. `api` instead of `nonplayApi`. To avoid runtime crashes, I need to also add the nonplayApi dependencies in my app module.

How do I get my flavour specific `nonplayApi` or `playApi` dependencies to include transitively in my app module?